# Convert Bsurface (without object) to mesh

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, conversion

I am trying to join 3 objects. They should be 3 meshes (which i created starting from bsurface). Somehow when i try to join them it says "Active object is not a selected mesh". Also the mesh icon does not appear. Alt+C seems not to do anything. **How can i convert it to a mesh!!** 
Thanks for your help,
Lluís
I belive the problem resides in that i made a retopo with bsurface but without the 1st step (add a object -> enter edit mode-> delete the plane-> start! ). Nevertheless i can see it like this: 
[image: full screen]

*(Outliner View. Objects: Plane, Plane.001 and Plane.00)

[image: Outliner View. Objects: Plane, Plane.001 and Plane.002]

Comment: I don't know how you used Bsurfaces, it should convert GPencil strokes to mesh  itself. There are objects with added GPencil layers shown; those aren't even curves yet and they can't be converted to mesh this way. Objects are also unselectable so they aren't selected

Comment: mhmm so how can i convert it to curves and then meshes? I can see the "mesh" and i can edit it, sculpt it...

Comment: Maybe i didnt add a plane before using bsurfaces.. I dont know if that could be the problem :S

Comment: What i bsurfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer in this comunity and blenderartist.The problem was that i needed to click on the little arrow (selection off/on) next to the object.
Wasn't aware of that. 
Thanks, lluis
i leave here the posts:
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?441827-Bsurface-without-object&p=3263344&highlight=#post3263344
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?441827-Bsurface-without-object&p=3263344&highlight=#post3263344